# Running NLTK sentence_bleu in Pandas

Tags: pandas, nltk, bleu

I am trying to apply sentence_bleu to a column in Pandas to rate the quality of some machine translation. But the scores it is outputting are incorrect. Can anyone see my error?

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu

translations = {
    'reference': [['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'],['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'],['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']],
    'candidate': [['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'],['this', 'is', 'not','a', 'quiz'],['I', 'like', 'kitties', '.']]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(translations)

df['BLEU'] = df.apply(lambda row: sentence_bleu(row['reference'],row['candidate']), axis=1)
df
```

It outputs this:

```
Index   reference   candidate   BLEU
0   [this, is, a, test] [this, is, a, test] 1.288230e-231
1   [this, is, a, test] [this, is, not, a, quiz]    1.218332e-231
2   [this, is, a, test] [I, like, kitties, .]   0.000000e+00
```

Row 0 should be equal to 1.0 and row 1 should be less than 1.0. Probably around 0.9. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently comparing the strings inside of the list. Since these strings only contain single words, the score will rate all n-grams with n > 1 directly as 0.

Instead you want your reference to be `['this is a test']` (a list of ground truth references), and the candidate to be `'this is a test'` (a single candidate).

```
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu

translations = {
    'reference': [['this is a test'],['this is a test'],['this is a test']],
    'candidate': ['this is a test','this is not a test','I like kitties']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(translations)

df['BLEU'] = df.apply(lambda row: sentence_bleu(row['reference'],row['candidate']), axis=1)
df
```

Which results into:

```
          reference           candidate           BLEU
0  [this is a test]      this is a test   1.000000e+00
1  [this is a test]  this is not a test   7.037906e-01
2  [this is a test]      I like kitties  6.830097e-155
```